# How to split lists that have multiple items within a dimension?

Tags: python

How would I split this? I'm been trying to find documentation on splits, especially with Pandas but unfortunately am unable to find something suitable for this.

Essentially I have two lists:

```
final = [([1,2],[0]),([0,1],[2]),([0,2],[1])]
```

How would I split this back so it could show:

```
first_tuple = [[1,2],[0,1],[0,2]]
second_tuple = [[0],[2],[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `zip`:

```
final = [([1,2],[0]),([0,1],[2]),([0,2],[1])]
first_tuple, second_tuple = zip(*final)
print(first_tuple)
print(second_tuple)
```

Which yields

```
([1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 2])
([0], [2], [1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer above, another option is to simply loop and subscript the values using list comprehension.

```
final = [([1,2],[0]),([0,1],[2]),([0,2],[1])]

first = [item[0] for item in final]
second = [item[1] for item in final]
print(first)
print(second)
```